# input for typing game using python and pygame isnt being processed

Tags: python

I am creating a typing game where the user has to type a prompt and the win condition is if the user enters it at atleast a speed of 35 wpm or greater. I had the code first written for execution in the console and started working on the gui using pygame later, this is the code without GUI:

```
from time import time
from random import randint

def typingErrors(prompt):
    global iwords

    words = prompt.split()
    errors = 0

    for i in range(len(iwords)):
        if i in (0, len(iwords)-1):
            if iwords[i] == words[i]:
                continue
            else:
                errors +=1
        else:
            if iwords[i] == words[i]:
                if (iwords[i+1] == words[i+1]) & (iwords[i-1] == words[i-1]):
                    continue
                else:
                    errors += 1
            else:
                errors += 1
    return errors

def typingSpeed(iprompt, stime, etime):
    global time
    global iwords

    iwords = iprompt.split()
    twords = len(iwords)
    speed = twords / time

    return speed

def timeElapsed(stime, etime):
    time = etime - stime

    return time

def GeneratePrompt():
    with open(r"C:\Users\adarshrsm\Desktop\prompts.txt", 'r') as file:
        prompts=file.readlines()
        for i in prompts:
            if len(i)>=10 and len(i)<30:
                try:
                    index = randint(0,(len(prompts)))
                    finalprompt=prompts[index]
                except IndexError:
                    GeneratePrompt()
    return finalprompt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #prompt = input("Enter Prompt: ")
    prompt=GeneratePrompt()
    print("Type this to open the chest:- '", prompt, "'")
    input("press ENTER when you are ready!")
    stime = time()
    iprompt = input()
    etime = time()
    time = round(timeElapsed(stime, etime), 2)
    speed = typingSpeed(iprompt, stime, etime)
    errors = typingErrors(prompt)
    accuracy = ((len(iwords)-errors)/len(iwords))*100
    wpm = round(speed,2)*60

    if accuracy == 100 and wpm >= 35:
        print("You have passed")
    else:
        print("You have failed")
```

Here is the code implemented using GUI:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
from time import time
from random import randint
#import RPGtext

#--------------------------Functions--------------------------------

def GeneratePrompt():
    with open(r"C:\Users\adarshrsm\Desktop\prompts.txt", 'r') as file:
        prompts=file.readlines()
        for i in prompts:
            if len(i)>=10 and len(i)<25:
                try:
                    index = randint(0,(len(prompts))+1)
                    finalprompt=prompts[index]
                except IndexError or UnboundLocalError:
                    GeneratePrompt()
    return finalprompt


def typingSpeed(iprompt, stime, etime):
    global time
    global iwords

    iwords = iprompt.split()
    twords = len(iwords)
    speed = twords / time

    return speed

def timeElapsed(stime, etime):
    time = etime - stime

    return time       
  

#-------------------------GUI and main game loop-----------------------------------

pygame.init()
Win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,900))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
chest_left_tilt = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\adarshrsm\Downloads\chest_left_tilt.png")
chest_right_tilt = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\adarshrsm\Downloads\right tilt.png")
chest_no_tilt = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\adarshrsm\Downloads\no tilt.png")
display_textbox = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\adarshrsm\Downloads\final textbox.png")
display_textbox.set_alpha(100)
txtf = pygame.font.Font(r"C:\Users\adarshrsm\Downloads\game font.ttf",40)
snip = txtf.render('',True,(0,0,0))
EnterPrompt = txtf.render("Enter this code to open the chest: ",True,(0,0,0))
EnterPrompt.set_alpha(200)
EnterLine = "Press Enter to start"
counter = 0
speed = 3
TextRendered = False
imgtick = 1
displayprompt = GeneratePrompt()
text = txtf.render(displayprompt,True,(0,0,0))
user_text = ''  
GameStatus = True


while GameStatus == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()                   
    if imgtick%100 == 0:
        Win.blit(chest_left_tilt,(0,0))
        imgtick+=1
    elif imgtick%100 != 0:
        Win.blit(chest_right_tilt,(0,0))
        imgtick+=1
        
    Win.blit(display_textbox,(100,50))    
    Win.blit(EnterPrompt,(150,100))
    
    if counter < speed * len(displayprompt):
        counter+=1
    elif counter >= speed * len(displayprompt):
        done = True
    snip = txtf.render(displayprompt[0:counter//speed],True,(0,0,0))
    EnterLineRender = txtf.render(EnterLine[0:counter//speed],True,(0,0,0))
    EnterLineRender.set_alpha(200)
    Win.blit(snip,(150,150))
    Win.blit(EnterLineRender,(150,200))
    user_text_list = []
    for event in pygame.event.get():    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                user_text = user_text[:-1]
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                stime = time()
            else:
                user_text += event.unicode
    
    if user_text == displayprompt:
        iprompt = user_text
        etime = time()
        time = round(timeElapsed(stime, etime), 2)
        speed = typingSpeed(iprompt, stime, etime)
        wpm = round(speed,2)*60 
                
        if wpm >=35:
            snip_win = txtf.render('',True,(0,0,0))
            counter_win = 0
            result_win = "You have unlocked the chest ! "
            if counter_win < speed * len(result_win):
                counter_win+=1
            elif counter_win >= speed * len(result_win):
                done = True
                snip_win = txtf.render(result_win[0:counter_win//speed],True,(0,0,0))
                Win.blit(snip_win,(150,350))
            else:
                snip_lose = txtf.render('',True,(0,0,0))
                counter_lose = 0
                result_lose = "You have failed to unlock the chest ! "
                if counter_lose < speed * len(result_lose):
                    counter_lose+=1
                elif counter_lose >= speed * len(result_lose):
                    done = True
                snip_lose = txtf.render(result_lose[0:counter_lose//speed],True,(0,0,0))
                Win.blit(snip_lose,(150,350))                    
                     
    user_text_surface = txtf.render(user_text,True,(0,0,0))        
    Win.blit(user_text_surface, (150,250)) 

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(100)
```

For some reason the processing of the user entered text doesnt take place, my suspicion is in the line "if user_text == displayprompt:" for some reason the user_text isnt being stored, or i am completely wrong here. Tried playing around with indentations and even tried implementing a for loop and appended the characters to a list and compared but still doesnt work. Rectification of errors in the code is greatly appreciated!

Basically Once the user has entered the prompt, nothing happens. The code doesnt compare it to the displayprompt and carry out the relevant processing and im at a loss for solutions

Answer (score 1):

You have this statement *inside* of your game loop, which is the the main problem:

```
user_text_list = []
```

Every time your screen refreshes, you are re-initializing to an empty list.  Move the creation of the list *outside* of your game loop (up before you start the `while` loop).